# portable way to terminate command (netcat) after timeout

Tags: netcat

I've got a solution using `netcat` / `nc` as a service listening for input, but the service never returns any input to the client. Somewhat like this:

```
server$ nc -l 12345
```

and then:

```
client$ echo message | nc server 12345
```

The trick is that because the server never sends anything back to the client (including no EOF), essentially because it doesn't know when the client is done, the client `netcat` never terminates.

One easy solution is to have the client use the `-q <secs>` option to `netcat`, but not all implementations (e.g. FreeBSD and Mac OSX) of `netcat` include the `-q` option.

Any other workarounds from the brilliant minds here?